# Sewer drain cap replacement options

Tags: plumbing, basement, sewer, plumbing-fixture

I have sewer cap that has lost its threads.  I am wondering what options I have to replace/fix that does not involving tearing up the cement floor.  Are compression fittings a good option?  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You can buy rubber "test plugs" of the appropriate size. They look like this one sold by Zoro Tools:

[image]